# Inverse of part of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

I am trying to write a proof and, in order to do so, I have to simplify the following

$$ \left( E H B^{-1} \right)^b \bigg(\big(V-VH(B+HVH)^{-1}HV\big)^{bb}\bigg)^{-1}$$

where $b$ indicates the rows that should be taken from the matrix and $bb$ indicates the block that should be taken from the matrix, and $X^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $X$. I am hence dealing with inverses of parts of a block matrix and I want to simplify this, so that i can work with matrices instead. Are there any useful books or properties that I can use?

Comment: $b$ is not a great index.  $i$, $j$, $k$ would have been nicer

Comment: Please clarify the "taken from" part.  Are you removing, say, the 1st row thereby obtaining a smaller matrix, or are you replacing the 1st row with zeros?

Comment: bb indicates rows b and columns b from the matrix (V−VH(B+HVH)−1HV). We hence obtain a smaller matrix

Comment: Take the $n \times n$ identity matrix and remove its $k$-th row.  What happens when you left-multiply a $n \times n$ matrix by this matrix?